# Convexity of quadratic form with respect to new set of parameters

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

I understand that the quadratic form, $f(x) = x^TAx$, is convex with respect to $x$ so long as the matrix $A$ is positive semi-definite.

If we assume that $A$ remains positive semi-definite, is the more general expression:

$f(\theta) = x^T(\theta)Ax(\theta)$

also convex with respect to the parameters $\theta$?

Is the answer an obvious yes or is there more to this that I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

In this sense, the function $f$ is actually a composition function, i.e., $f(\theta) = h(g(\theta))$, where $g(\theta) = x(\theta)\colon \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^k$ and $h(x) = x^TAx \colon \mathbb{R}^k \to \mathbb{R}$. If we do not know any more information of function $g$, it is difficult to determine the convexity of $f$.

Here is a counterexample. Let $k=n=2$, $g(\theta) = (\theta_1^2, -\theta_2^2)$, and $A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$. Now the function
\begin{equation}
f(\theta) = \theta_1^4 - 2\theta_1^2\theta_2^2 + \theta_2^4
\end{equation}
is not convex.

Comment: Great. Thank you for the response. Besides the obvious linear parameterization case, $x(\theta) = \sum_i c_i\theta_i$, would there be a simple way of knowing which cases admit convexity? Or does it simply boil down to a case-by-case basis requiring the calculation of the Hessian every time?

Comment: @GFlash, Maybe you can refer to Stephen Boyd's Book [convex optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf) (Page. 83), They analyze 
 the convexity of some specific composite functions. (But it seems that the situation you are considering is not included)